# Making a simple sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

1. **Managers must make changes that are consistent with their firm's structure.**
2. **Managers must make changes in their strategies.**

My objective is to make a simple sentence using the sentences 1&2.

Can I rewrite the sentences in this way?

A. **In their strategies, managers must make changes that are consistent with their firm's structure.**

B. **Managers must make changes in their strategies, that are consistent with their firm's structure.**

Are there other ways to rewrite the sentence? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a good idea to run your writing through a spell checker to catch the typos, like "ovjective"

Answer (score 1):

Your structure for B is correct. You can further simplify B to "Managers must make changes in their strategies consistent with their firm's structure."

A is incorrect. Your wording does not establish that the structure of the firm is what the manager must change.

You can also word this as: "Changes in managerial strategy must be consistent with firm structure."